# Sign Out Of All Accounts When RedirectURI returns to guarded application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSALjs to logout a user on my application. When the `msalService.logoutRedirect()` is triggered, the page redirects and is logged out. However, my application does not have an "un-guarded" route, thus the redirect after logout (`postLogoutRedirectUri`) is set to return to the application's last active page. And when it returns to the application, the MSAL guard automatically finds a valid MS session and logs back in again automatically (after redirects).

If I change the `postLogoutRedirectUri` to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout`, the logout does work and I am signed out correctly. However, I would like to immediately be prompted to sign back in, which is why I intend on returning to the application so the MsalGuard can prompt sign in.

Per a recent [GitHub issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/4345) , one of the MSAL contributors said the following:

> This is a nuance of how B2C works. By default B2C might not log you out of your federated identity provider when you call the logout endpoint, this is explained in more detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow#sign-out). I unfortunately don't know enough about B2C configuration to give you a definitive answer but you may need to create a custom policy which redirects to the AAD logout endpoint you mentioned: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout' as this endpoint is the one that ultimately closes your session with AAD. You can also have B2C pass through your postLogoutRedirectUri to this endpoint so that AAD redirects you back to your application after the logout instead of ending on the "Close this window" screen, if desired.

How can I set this up so the logout is triggered correctly and all sessions are signed out?

Furthermore, if I manually change the metadata of the openid-config to have the `"end_session_endpoint"` equal to the microsoftonline logout link from above, the behavior seems to be more in line with what I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could send the apps post logout redirect uri to the federated IdPs logout url. You can set the postLogoutRedirectURI in MSAL config object.

And at the federated IdP, set the logout url to the application.

Approach only works if you are using 1 federated IdP, and is the only IdP available.

```js
function signOut() {
    const logoutRequest = {
     postLogoutRedirectUri: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?
post_logout_redirect_uri=https://myapp.com"
     msalConfig.auth.redirectUri
    };
    myMSALObj.logoutPopup(logoutRequest);
}
```

Otherwise, make an unguarded page in your app that redirects to the guarded page, but sets the MSAL prompt parameter to “login”. At least then the B2C login page will appear, and allow the user to select how they want to login. They may still get SSO if they select a federated IdP.

Comment: Thank you very much. So in the B2C Manifest there is a `logout` url. Is this the place for the federated IdP or do I need to change the "end_session_endpoint" from OpenID Connect? To set the logout to the application

Comment: No, in your code, set the postLogoutRedirectURI in the MSAL config object directly to the logout endpoint of the federated IdP (seems like it’s AAD). That URL itself will contain a postLogoutURI parameter, and should be set to your apps URL.

Comment: I see. I was thinking this would be a B2C Config. How could I handle this with environments? redirect to `myapp.com` vs `dev.myapp.com` vs `test.myapp.com`? I guess I would set this up in the env variables but seems like an extra step that may not be necessary?

Comment: Some sort of env variable, yes, or similar to how you manage other env based params in your code.